# PHP time math calculations

Tags: php, math, time

Hallo,

How can I calculate a current time moment + exactly one week?
The same with month.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the function [`strtotime()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) - very useful.

```
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
```

Comment: @stck777: I edited a link to the function documentation in your answer for the benefit of the OP, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```